# Wants to achieve array with count of similar values in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object in jQuery

```
obj[{timestamp:1499385600},{timestamp:1499385600},{timestamp:1499385600}, {timestamp:1499299200}, {timestamp:1499299200}, ...]
```

Now i need an object where i will have all counts of particular timestamp as name, value pair. for example.

```
{{timestamp: 1499385600, count: 3}, {timestamp: 1499299200, count:2}}
```

Not able to understand how to iterate the loop here.
So far i have done

```
var newobj={};
for(i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
   newobj['timestamp']=obj[i].timestamp;
   newobj['count']=//Not sure what to write here to get the count
}
```

suggestion are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The objects in your samples are syntactically wrong. Could you give a clearer sample of your data

Comment: is this correct `,{timestamp:1499385600]`?

Comment: [{timestamp:1499385600},{timestamp:1499385600},{timestamp:1499385600}, {timestamp:1499299200}, {timestamp:1499299200}, ...]....This is how it is objects inside array

Comment: no. `obj[{` this is also incorrect which Rory asked

Comment: @SandeepPujare add it into question

Comment: @SandeepPujare I think you are referring to an array as object. Also, object cannot contain another object without a key. Do you need the answer as `[ { obj }, { obj }, { obj } ]`

Comment: I have just edited my question...

Comment: Yes Anurag. Exactly

Comment: objects inside array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring all the syntax error in your question and taking appropriate assumptions, this is probably what you want to do:

```js
var data = [
  {timestamp:1499385600},
  {timestamp:1499385600},
  {timestamp:1499385600}, 
  {timestamp:1499299200}, 
  {timestamp:1499299200}
];

var groups = data.reduce(function(acc, obj){
  acc[obj.timestamp] = acc[obj.timestamp] || 0;
  acc[obj.timestamp] += 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

var result = Object.keys(groups).map(function(key) {
  return {
    timestamp : key,
    count : groups[key]
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

First create a map which keeps track of count of same timestamp values using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) then create the final array with the help of [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

After the loop is completed you want `newObj` to look something like:

```
{
   '1499385600':6,
   '1499299200':2
}
```

Then you can iterate `newObj` to create the new array you want

```
// create counter object
var newobj = {};
for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
    // use current object timestamp as key
    // if undefined (first time found) make it zero +1 
    // otherwise add 1 to prior count                                
    newobj[obj[i].timestamp] = (newobj[obj[i].timestamp] || 0) +1;
}
// create results array from counter object
var results = [];
for(var time in newObj){
   results.push( { timestamp: time, count: newObj[time] });
}
```